# What should I do when my defect is rejected?

Tags: manual-testing

What should testers do if the developer rejects the issue posted on the defect tracking tool?

As I am using a defect tracking tool where a developer has done this I want to know: can I ask him to resolve, or is there any other way?

Comment: Why has the developer rejected to resolve?

Comment: See Natasha, As QA it is our responsibility to find and post bug with severity. Off the conventional flow, You can make conversation with Developer to resolve bug. If developer is not making it resolved then do not worry so much. You have completed your duty. If client will ask you then you can show the bug and also they can see who has reject it. :D So every time you win.

Comment: I think you could refer the exact section of the specification that indicates what the application should do. Ideally, that is objective to show why you marked it a defect.

Comment: Learn about bug advocacy. See questions like [How to sell a bug?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/29245/25505) and others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also option in defect tracking tools for comments by developers. When developer rejects some defect on defect tracking tool, he also mention his or her comments there. You can read that for the reason of rejecting. Then you can personally discuss with the developer.

Often it happens that a defect coming on your pc does not happen in developer pcs. *It is said as defect has not REPRODUCED on developer pc.* Tester should first check this on his own machine that whether is coming or not. Then tester job is then to try to reproduce it on the developer pc.

There may be several reasons due to which defect is not reproduced on developer pc. Few of them mentioned below(mostly related to web applications):

1) Check the configuration of your application whether it is same on your pc and developer pc. For example there may be some configuration parameter in your application which you are testing that may not be set same in developer pc as it is on your testing environment.

2) Check the configuration of browsers on which you are testing your application if it is web application. For example in IE often this issue raised due to the different document modes(by pressing f12 in IE).

Another example of this is compatible modes setting on developer and tester browsers should be same.

3)Screen layout defects can be rejected due to different screen resolutions on tester and developer machines.

4)Often just cleaning the cache of browsers of developer machine sometimes reproduced the defect.

5) Often it happens that developer has tested it on desktop while tester has tested it on laptops.

6) Often it happens that tester raise some defect but that is just coming due to *refreshing* not done since long time on your application being tested. These defects do not come on developer machines so got rejected.

7) Some times developers do not check it carefully(there may some negligence on their part). In this case tester should consult developer and try to reproduce the defect on their machines.

A similar question can be found at 
[ui-validation-bug-not-reproducible-on-dev-environment](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/30069/ui-validation-bug-not-reproducible-on-dev-environment/30372#30372)

Comment: okay now i get that... TYSM :)

Answer (score 2):

In our software qa company developers provide's resolution (Not a Bug, Cannot Reproduce) for the defect.

You can check resolution or ask developer to provide resolution for the defect.

Further if you want the bug to be fixed as it is impacting the release, you can increase the severity of the defect and Assign the defect to Product owner.

Answer (score 2):

So far as per my 3+ QA experience,

It's depends on your bug severity, If it really a bug and can impact the product some where. In this case if you really thinks that particular issue should be resolved but developer is not ready to resolved it then you have to approach you upper level person. Somewhere your QA team Lead if not there and you are assigned individually to a development team then you have to approach him/her.

In this case you have to accept the decision what your senior person has taken. and maintain the status and comment in that issue.

But if you are facing developer only then you have to take developer comment in that task. Why that issue can not resolve. So in future nobody blame you that why don't you raise this issue before.

If its a suggestion only and not mentioned anywhere so hardly. So in that case you can also take decision to close.